# How to create my own checker in Midje?

Tags: clojure, midje

I'm using Midje for a project. I've tried to find in the wiki how could I create my own checker, but couldn't find it.

In my case, I want to compare if two images are equal. But it could be that I just want to compare some properties of the file, as it's size, perhaps a couple of pixels. Perhaps the "equality" would be a bit flexible, hence the need of a personalised checker.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a wiki page](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Writing-your-own-checkers) in midje github repo describing how to define your own checkers.

A checker used on the right hand side of an arrow is a plain predicate function accepting the result of left hand side.

In your example scenario, you can just create your own function for checking a file:

```
(defn filename-matches? [expected-name]
  (fn filename-matcher [actual-file]
    (= expected-name (.getAbsolutePath actual-file))))
```

Then you can use it in your tests:

```
(generate-file) => (filename-matches? "output.txt")
```

If you would like use checkers on the left hand side of an arrow you need to follow instructions on [another wiki page](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Checkers-within-prerequisites).

And if you are not satisfied by the format of failure messages generated when using plain predicate functions, you can use some tools described on wiki page discussing [chatty checkers](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Chatty-checkers).